# should Jenkins (AKA hudson) be installed on the actual build server?

Tags: hudson, clearcase, jenkins

hello
i want to install a central build server that will serve all my other build servers (different OS's). 
should Jenkins be installed on this central machine or should i install it on the main build server (windows based)?
in addition, what is the master-slave relationship means?
does it mean that i can run a build from the master but it will actually run on the slave?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build server can have a Jenkins slave, that is can be declared on the Hudson master instance (itself installed on a dedicated server) in order to be run according to the job specifications registered at said master.

The Jenkins master is just a scheduler, and will execute jobs either on the Jenkins master server itself, or on any server registered as slave.

The idea to isolate the master on its own server, rather than having it directly in the build server, is to:

- administer the Jenkins master server independently from the build server
- avoid taking resources (disk space, cpu) from the build processes on the build server
- not making all the other jobs depending on the state of the build server (if said server goes down, no other jobs would be executed)

The script actually executed on the build server can then declare/use locally whatever ClearCase snapshot or dynamic view it needs to access the relevant sources, depending on how the Jenkins [ClearCase job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin), [ClearCase UCM job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Baseline+Plugin) or [ClearCase Release job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Release+Plugin) has been configured.

[image: base cc example]

You don't need for that to have the server directly on the build server.

Comment: so i have another questions...  how can i setup the slave? both master and slave are  windows based machines. should i install jenkins on both and just click on create node?

Comment: @Mavig: the principle behind a slave is to give access (ssh or other) for the master to execute jobs. No local Jenkins installation should be necessary.

Comment: thanks! :) so excuse me for my ignorance... how can i actually do it on windows? is there any walkthrough or a step by step guide?

Comment: @Mavig: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallSlaveasaWindowsservice(require.Net2framework) can help: the idea is to install a small jar which will do the listening, enabling the slave to execute whatever script/command the master will send. http://yakiloo.com/setup-jenkins-and-windows/ can help too.

Comment: @VonC: thanks a lot!!!!! i have finally seen the option to install as a windows service.. now i get the status code 500 :( so it cannot e installed... any idea?

Comment: @Mavig: that code 500? (http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html) on the client? If yes, you need to check logs on the Jenkins master server, because there was some kind of error on the server side.

Comment: INFO: Finished Fingerprint cleanup. 16 ms

May 12, 2011 10:22:33 AM hudson.model.FingerprintCleanupThread execute
INFO: Cleaned up 0 records

May 12, 2011 10:22:33 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Fingerprint cleanup

May 12, 2011 10:17:44 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Connection Activity monitoring to slaves. 0 ms

May 12, 2011 10:17:44 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Connection Activity monitoring to slaves

Comment: @Mavig: so no obvious error on the server. Are you running jenkins directly with Java, or in a server container like Jetty? See http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4804 as an example of code error 500 because of a container.

Comment: @Mavig: well SO does have a chat interface. See you there

Comment: @Mavig: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/784/jenkins, but I don't think I can invite you in, and I am not sure you have enough rep to join.

Comment: @VonC: i can't :( do you have ny phone number i can call you? "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow"

Comment: @Mavig: I try to limit my answers through SO and/or SO chat. I have entered a bug report meantime: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90969/chat-can-i-grant-write-access-to-a-unregistered-user

Comment: you are not online and i have to go. can we chat on sunday at around this time or even earlier? (where are you located? i am GMT +2)

Comment: @VonC: great. so can we schedule for sunday at aroun 10am?

Comment: @Mavig: I won't be available this w-end, rather next Monday. But in the meantime, if you can isolate the exact steps and problems you are currently facing, that could be the base for a new SO question, allowing you to move forward without depending on a single external resource ;)

Comment: @VonC: i did isolate everything. what time on Monday? :) thanks a lot for willing to help :)